Copy a sheet with hyperlinks
Can I copy a sheet that I have 60 Hyperlinks in and have the hyperlinks automatically reference to the new sheet (i.e. in sheet "A" I have Hyperlinks at A1 to A60  that send me to a specified cell number Eg (in A1 'A'!AT633 which sends me to cell AT633 when clicked on) to make it quicker to get around the sheet) At the moment when I copy the sheet Named "A" and Name the newly copied sheet "B" when I use the link in Sheet "B" it sends me back to Sheet 'A'!AT633 not 'B'!AT633 I hope I have explained my problem ok any help would be appreciated.

Copy the links, then try Paste special - see if there is a suitable option. (no Excel to check this)

thanks for the answer Already tried that still does not change the name of the hyperlink to the correct sheet

After paste, Try Search & Replace, "in formulas".

hi Hannu thanks for the suggestion excuse me if i sound a bit stupid but i dont know how to use search and replace in formulas

In the dialog that opens up for "Search", is an option to "Search in formulas" (again: from memory, no Excel available)
